# Why does the Save button requires two clicks to hit the associated function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

The Anchor tag is used here like a button and the knockout click binding is associated to a function on the view model. Why it is requiring two clicks for the function to be invoked?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PositionModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        self.listPosition = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        if (self.listPosition == undefined) {
            self.listPosition = ko.observableArray();
        }
        self.selectedItemPosition = ko.observable();
        self.positionToEdit = ko.observable();

        self.addPosition = function () {
            var newItem = ko.mapping.fromJS({
                Id: 0,
                Name: ''
            });
            self.listPosition.splice(0, 0, newItem);
            self.listPosition.valueHasMutated();
            self.positionToEdit(newItem);
            $('#txtPositionName').focus();
        };

        self.savePosition = function () {
            var item = self.positionToEdit();

            self.positionToEdit(null);
        };

        self.selectPosition = function (item) {
            ////////debugger;
            self.selectedItemPosition(item);
        }

        self.templateToUsePosition = function (item) {
            console.log(item.Name());
            var compare = self.positionToEdit();
            var str = compare === item ? 'editTmplPosition' : 'itemsTmplPosition';
            return str;
        };

        self.editPosition = function (item) {
            self.positionToEdit(item);
        };

    };

    $(function () {

        ko.applyBindings(new PositionModel([{
            Id: 1,
            Name: 'abc'
        }, { Id: 2, Name: 'def' }]));

    });
</script>
<div id="abcd">
    <div>

        <table  style="width: 400px">
            <p>
                <a  data-bind="click: addPosition" href="#" title="edit">Add</a>
            </p>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" >position</a>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 100px; text-align: right;" />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="template: { name: templateToUsePosition, foreach: listPosition }" />
        </table>

        <script id="itemsTmplPosition" type="text/html">
            <tr style="width: auto" data-bind="click: $parent.selectPosition">
                <td style="width: auto" data-bind="text: Name" />
                <td  style="width: 200px">
                    <a  data-bind="click: $parent.editPosition" href="#" title="edit">
                        edit
                    </a>
                    <a  data-bind="click: $parent.removePosition" href="#" title="remove">
                        remove
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </script>
        <script id="editTmplPosition" type="text/html">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input style="width: auto" id="txtPositionName" data-bind="value: Name" />
                </td>
                <td >
                    <a  data-bind="click: $parent.savePosition" href="javascript:void(0);" title="save">
                        save
                    </a>
                    <a  data-bind="click: $parent.cancelSavingPosition" href="#" title="cancel">
                        cancel
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please shorten your example code to only the minimum needed for the question, and in addition tell us what you've found while debugging / what you've tried to solve it and why it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have time to create a proper answer but here is the solution: just remove the `console.log(item.Name());` from your `templateToUsePosition` and your code should work.

Comment: But, can you tell me the reason why removing this statement works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With writing `console.log(item.Name());` into your `templateToUsePosition` function you have created a dependency on the `Name` property in the K[O dependency tracking mechanism.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#how-dependency-tracking-works)

So every time when your `item.Name()` changes your `templateToUsePosition` will be reevaluated.

So this is what happens in your code:

- You click on edit which changes `positionToEdit` which triggers your `templateToUsePosition` function and turn your UI to edit mode
- You enter something in the textbox and click on the save link
- Because the textbox loses the focus it updates your `Name` property
- Because the `templateToUsePosition` has a dependency on the `Name` property it is triggered again and rebuilds your UI, so your original click event on the original save link is lost and you have to click again.
- One the second click there is no change in the `Name` so it the click even normally goes through.

So to solve this problem you just need to remove the `console.log(item.Name());`.

However if you still need to use the value of `item.Name` in your `templateToUsePosition` and you don't want to create a dependency then **you need to use the `peek()` method** on the observable:

```
console.log(item.Name.peek());
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayBLC/).